# Jquery add events to dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, events, copy

Greetings fellow coders :)
Through the API I'm using some HTML tags have events bound to them. My problem is I don't know how to add new elements(tags) that will have the same properties and events as the hardcoded elements.

Answer (score 3):

You want to look into jquery live event bindings.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

This will let you define handlers for events that get applied to even dynamically created elements.

Bob

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to do it. I googled a lot for the events I need to bind to my elements, but I couldn't find anything. Basically, I don't know what to bind....

Comment: If you want more specific help, try posting some code for your elements/events and Ajax.